# Проблема с 500 Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, сервер, flask

Нужно решить проблему со входом на 127.0.0.1:5000/status. На интенсиве я постарался написать json для сервера, но получаю Internal Server Error при переходе по вышеуказанной ссылке. Что поменять в коде можно?

```
from flask import Flask
import datetime
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

status = {
    "time": datetime.datetime.now(),
    "name": "PARROTHI",
    "status": True
}

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Welcome for all!"


@app.route("/status")
def status():
    return json.dumps(status)

app.run()
```

Comment: `Internal Server Error ` ни о чем не говорит, смотрите в консоли сервера что за ошибка. И включайте у `app` режим отладки: `app.debug = True`

Answer (score 2):

У вас имя функции совпадает с именем переменной, поэтому в `json.dumps` попадала ссылка на функцию. Попробуйте переименовать переменную, например в `status_data`

И у `flask` для возврата `JSON` есть функцию `jsonify`

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

status_data = {
...

@app.route("/status")
def status():
    return jsonify(status_data)
```

---

Покажу разницу между `return json.dumps(status_data)` и `return jsonify(status_data)`:

```
...
status_data = {
    # NOTE: по умолчанию json.dumps не умеет работать, в отличии от jsonify, с типом datetime.datetime,
    #       поэтому поместил вместо него его строковое представление
    "time": str(datetime.datetime.now()),
    "name": "PARROTHI",
    "status": True
}

@app.route("/status1")
def status1():
    return jsonify(status_data)

@app.route("/status2")
def status2():
    return json.dumps(status_data)
...
```

#### return jsonify(status_data)

Как видно, от сервера пришел заголовок `Content-Type-application/json` из-за этого клиент понимает, что это `JSON` (и браузер `Firefox` для этого типа подсунул удобный редактор):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

#### return json.dumps(status_data)

Возвращая просто строку из метода, сервер передал `Content-Type=text/html; charset=utf-8`, т.е. для клиента это просто текст `HTML`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPD.**

Добавил полный пример:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import datetime
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

status_data = {
    # NOTE: по умолчанию json.dumps не умеет работать, в отличии от jsonify, с типом datetime.datetime,
    #       поэтому поместил вместо него его строковое представление
    "time": str(datetime.datetime.now()),
    "name": "PARROTHI",
    "status": True
}

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return """
    Welcome for all!
    <br>
    <a href="/status1">/status1</>
    <br>
    <a href="/status2">/status2</>
    """

@app.route("/status1")
def status1():
    return jsonify(status_data)

@app.route("/status2")
def status2():
    return json.dumps(status_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

Comment: Так где можно проверить json?

Comment: @parrothi, что значит проверить json? То, что я написал, это добавил в ваш код, после запустил сервер и открыл в браузере

Comment: А в яндекс.браузере или гугл-хроме нельзя открыть именно /status?

Comment: @parrothi, а вы про мое уточнение с firefox... ну он так отображает json, Chrome, насколько я помню, показывает как обычную страницы. Яндекс браузер скорее всего тоже, т.к. оба на одном движке

Comment: Если бы так и было... Но на обоих браузерах показывает уже заевшую меня цифру 500. Я кстати, пробовал обойтись без модуля json, а также поменял формат вывода времени. Я надеялся, что выведется это, как обычная строка, но вместо этого показывается ошибка.

Comment: @parrothi, дело не в браузерах -- те 500 приходят от сервера, вы сделали как я рекомендовал? Включите отладку у сервера и посмотрели в консоли сервера что там за ошибка. Добавил в ответ полный исправленный код

Answer (score 2):

В добавок к тому, что написано в соседнем ответе, объекты типа `datetime.datetime` не являются JSON-сериализуемыми, поэтому вы не можете сделать json.dumps для такого объекта. Для этого его нужно привести либо к строке, либо к timestamp.

Например так:

```
status = {
    "time": str(datetime.datetime.now()),  # вот так вот
    "name": "PARROTHI",
    "status": True
}
```

Кстати, с этим местом связана ещё одна проблема - так как у вас `status` определён за пределами функции, в глобальной области видимости, `datetime.now()` будет расчитываться один раз - в момент запуска программы.

Чтобы время бралось актуальное, нужно либо внести `status` в функцию, которая его использует, либо завернуть в отдельную функцию, которая будет вызываться там, где это значение понадобится.